# String Similarity Code changes

Tags: java

I programmed 1 code but it just passed 1 test case so i am not understanding what all mistake i did and what all changes do i got to make in the code so the question and the code is as follows:

**Question:**

For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2, while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.

Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes.

Input:
The first line contains the number of test cases T. Each of the next T lines contains a string each.

Output:
Output T lines containing the answer for the corresponding test case.

Constraints:
1 <= T <= 10
The length of each string is at most 100000 and contains only lower case characters.

Sample Input:
2
ababaa
aa

Sample Output:
11
3

Explanation:
For the first case, the suffixes of the string are "ababaa", "babaa", "abaa", "baa", "aa" and "a". The similarities of each of these strings with the string "ababaa" are 6,0,3,0,1,1 respectively. Thus the answer is 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11.

For the second case, the answer is 2 + 1 = 3.

Code:

**String Similarity**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution 
{
    int T,i;
    String[] S;
    String p;


    String inp;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int count=0;

    public void StringSimilarity()
    {

        try
        {
            T=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  
            if(T<1 && T>10)
                System.exit(0);
            S=new String[T];

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

            for(i=0;i<T;i++)
            {
                count=0;
             try
             {

                S[i]=br.readLine();
                S[i].toLowerCase();

             }
             catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }


        for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            int g=0;
            p=S[i];
            int a=0;
            a=p.length();
            count=0;
            char t[]=new char[a];


            for(int n=0;n<p.length();n++)
            {
                t[n]=p.charAt(n);

            }




            int m=p.length();

            for(int f=0;f<t.length;f++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<m-g;j++)
                {
                   if(p.charAt(0)== t[0])
                   {
                    if(p.charAt(j)== t[j])
                    {
                        count=count+1;

                    }
                   }
                }
                g=g+1;


                for(int k=0;k<t.length-1;k++)
                {
                    t[k]=t[k+1];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Solution s=new Solution();
        s.StringSimilarity();

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your post and clearly state what you are having trouble with. It is hard to tell since the description is vague and the code has no documentation.

Comment: Problem:  For the number T, I enter "Elton John" and your code continues with whatever T is initially assigned to (fortunately I don't think it will compile as is).

Comment: This is a problem from InterviewStreet's collection of challenges. Original problem statement is at https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4edb8abd7cacd

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is hard to read as it contains too many variables and is not correctly decomposed into smaller easily readable, maintainable, and testable parts. I tried to implement the solution to your problem in a much more straightforward way so that you could examine it, play with it and learn something from it. Hope it helps...

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.start();
  }

  private void start() {
    try {
      parse("x.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void parse(String filename) throws IOException {
    Reader r = null;
    try {
      r = new FileReader(filename);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] strings = line.split(" ");
        /* skip the first one, not important for us */
        for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
          System.out.println("RESULT: for '" + strings[i] + "' is " + computeSimilarity(strings[i]));
        }
      }
    } finally {
      if (r != null) {
        r.close();
      }
    }
  }

  private int computeSimilarity(String s) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      /* compare also with itself */
      result += compareSimilarity(s, s.substring(i));
    }
    System.out.println("  " + s + " -> " + result);
    return result;
  }

  private int compareSimilarity(String s1, String s2) {
    int result = 0;
    /* s1.length() > s2.length() */
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) {
        result++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("    " + s1 + " " + s2 + " -> " + result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

And its output for your test-data is:

```
    ababaa ababaa -> 6
    ababaa babaa -> 0
    ababaa abaa -> 3
    ababaa baa -> 0
    ababaa aa -> 1
    ababaa a -> 1
  ababaa -> 11
RESULT: for 'ababaa' is 11
    aa aa -> 2
    aa a -> 1
  aa -> 3
RESULT: for 'aa' is 3
```